# Add a new Taxonomy term page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8

[image]

[image]
I use drupal 8 and I want to add a new view page to taxonomy view.

I tried to dublicate default taxonomy page view and changed path

```
from: taxonomy/term/%/
to : taxonomy/term/%/newpath
```

but this is not working. why would this not work?

Comment: You can alter routes using a route subscriber service.

Comment: I dont want to alter current paths, I just want to create a new view for taxonomies ex: taxonomy/term/2/feed taxonomy/term/2/newpath

Comment: I thought you wanted to replace the current routes.

Comment: Add your entire route definition in the question body.

Comment: I didnt write a custom route for that. Only changed the path of a current taxonomy view

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". What do you get when you visit that path?

Comment: page not foundd.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to change the "**Contextual filter**" settings ?

**WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL** to -> Provide default value (taxonomy term from url)

or check the **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED** validation